# How to paginate a native query in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, dql

Doctrine 2 has the Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator class which can be used to paginate normal DQL queries.

However if I pass it a native query, I get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator::cloneQuery() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Query, instance of Doctrine\ORM\NativeQuery given
```

I've tried removing the type-hinting from the paginator class in the cloneQuery method, but this just gives further errors because other bits of the paginator class expect methods found in Query that aren't in NativeQuery.

Is there any easy way of paginating the native queries without needing to build a new paginator class or fetching every row from the database into an array?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that - At least I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made my own paginator adapter class compatible with Zend_Paginator.

Probably won't be the most flexible since it relies on there being a " FROM " near the start of the query (see the count() method) but it's a relatively quick and easy fix.

```
/**
 * Paginate native doctrine 2 queries 
 */
class NativePaginator implements Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface
{
    /**
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\NativeQuery
     */
    protected $query;
    protected $count;

    /**
     * @param Doctrine\ORM\NativeQuery $query 
     */
    public function __construct($query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the total number of rows in the result set.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function count()
    {
        if(!$this->count)
        {
            //change to a count query by changing the bit before the FROM
            $sql = explode(' FROM ', $this->query->getSql());
            $sql[0] = 'SELECT COUNT(*)';
            $sql = implode(' FROM ', $sql);

            $db = $this->query->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
            $this->count = (int) $db->fetchColumn($sql, $this->query->getParameters());
        }

        return $this->count;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an collection of items for a page.
     *
     * @param  integer $offset Page offset
     * @param  integer $itemCountPerPage Number of items per page
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
    {
        $cloneQuery = clone $this->query;
        $cloneQuery->setParameters($this->query->getParameters(), $this->query->getParameterTypes());

        foreach($this->query->getHints() as $name => $value)
        {
            $cloneQuery->setHint($name, $value);
        }

        //add on limit and offset
        $sql = $cloneQuery->getSQL();
        $sql .= " LIMIT $itemCountPerPage OFFSET $offset";
        $cloneQuery->setSQL($sql);

        return $cloneQuery->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the paginator is implemented, but beware of SQLi when passing parameter directly to SQL without escaping. Casting to int would be enough in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `dbal query builder` that you have constructed with

```
$yourDbalQueryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
```

then you can use:

```
$yourDbalQueryBuilder->setFirstResult(0)
                     ->setMaxResults(100000000)
                     ->execute()
                     ->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function countTotalRecords($query, string $primaryKey = '*'): int
    {
        if ($query instanceof QueryBuilder) {
            $paginator = new Paginator($query->getQuery());
            return count($paginator);
        } else if ($query instanceof NativeQuery) {
            $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($query->getEntityManager());
            $rsm->addScalarResult('count', 'count');

            $sqlCount = "select count(".$primaryKey.") as count from (" . $query->getSQL() . ") as item";

            $count = $query->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sqlCount, $rsm);

            if ($query->getParameter('limit')) {
                $query->setParameter('limit', null);
            }

            $count->setParameters($query->getParameters());

            return (int)$count->getSingleScalarResult();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify as to how this solves the problem?

Comment: is an example of how to return the total number of records in a native query or querybuilder, and each change in the offset returns the number of records remaining