# Doctrine, NativeQuery, Join and Limit for first entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I used Doctrine and `NativeQuery` (`setResultMapping`). In my query, I use multiple joins to fetch entities that are related using `OneToMany`. I want to create pagination only for my first entity (For in Html, one col and many data in one row (oneToMany)).

If I use `LIMIT 0, 20`, joins multiply the result and distorts it.

Can you help me ?

Comment: The only way I have seen to get around this is to do two queries.  The first is a SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM ... LIMIT 0,20.  You then take the resulting ids and execute a second query using WHERE id IN (:ids).  In some cases you might be able to reduce this to one query using a nested statement.

Answer (score 0):

With DQL queries, Doctrine's `Paginator` is your man - [Doctrine Docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html). What concerns `NativeQuery` there seems to be a solution in this post - [How to paginate a native query in Doctrine 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462836/how-to-paginate-a-native-query-in-doctrine-2)